# HTML object and audio tags

Tags: html, audio, object

These four snippets of code all work properly on my webpage if I open the page locally on my computer. But when I upload the webpage (and audio file) to a hosting server and access the page there through the internet, not all of them work properly as so:

This opened up windows media player on my computer and played the audio file through it even though it doesn't do that on the webpage accessed locally.

```
 <object height="50px" width="100px" autostart="false" data="Audio/MHXSEagle.mp3" >
 </object>
```

This works properly.

```
<object height="320px" width="240px" data="Audio/MHXSEagle.mp3" >
<param name="src" value="Audio/MHXSEagle.mp3"/>
</object>
```

These two work locally, but not through the internet:

```
<audio src="Audio/MHXSEagle.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"  preload="auto"> 
   Browser doesn't support audio tags
</audio>

<audio controls="controls"> 
    <source src="Audio/MHXSEagle.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
 Browser doesn't support audio tags
</audio>
```

I don't understand why they act differently and would like some clarification.

Comment: which browser are you testing on?

Comment: are you testing in a apache environment like XAMPP or just under windows?

Comment: I'm a beginner at web programming, so I don't understand what an "apache environment like XAMPP" is. I'm using Windows 7 with IE 9. I don't understand why it would work on my computer, but then not work online.

Comment: XAMPP is a webserver program that emulates a live server on a windows machine. apache is a webserver, you should google it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<audio />
```

audio tag is html 5 so IE 9 works, just tested on my server, but firefox does not work.
the object tag works on FF and chrome but IE seems to have issues on the server.
on my machine, IE doesnt seem to play anything local. 
my guess is that local windows and apache servers have an effect on IE but firefox seems to be consistent

Comment: Do you think you might know why <audio> might be working for me locally but not through the internet?

Comment: its hard to say without knowing more about your server, can you try different browsers?

Comment: I had tried using a ogg version of the mp3 file and with Firefox. Through the internet, each snippet works. But on my computer locally, the <object> snippets don't work but the <audio> snippets work fine

Comment: i only test locally using XAMPP because when files go live this is the most consistent way to test.  look it up, you will def be glad you did

Comment: the audio file on ypur page works for me since it's <object> with <param> inside. Ok I'll take a look at XAMPP